# Edge case $X = \varnothing$ in "there exists exactly one equivalence class"

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $\sim$ an equivalence
>   relation on $X$ such that every equivalence class is open. Then there
>   is only one equivalence class, namely $X$.

My question is NOT about the solution, but merely about the edge case $X = \varnothing$. The only equivalence relation on $X$ is the empty relation $\varnothing$. **So basically there is no equivalence class**. So did I misunderstood something or should one impose $X \neq \varnothing$ in this particular exercise?

**Edit.** I use the excellent book written by @[Jack Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee) in which the empty space IS connected (topological manifolds, p. 86). This is exercise 4.3, p.87.

Comment: I think the various definitions don't agree on whether-or-not $\varnothing$ is connected. ​ ​

Comment: Here are many examples of why $\varnothing$ should not be considered connected https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space#connectedness. Briefly, this is analogous to asking whether $1$ is a prime. A connected space is a space with exactly one connected component. $\varnothing$ has *zero* components, so may be considered trivially disconnected.

Comment: @RickyDemer Added reference.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Added.

Comment: You're right -- I should have excluded the empty set. I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: If the empty space counts as connected, then it needs to be explicitly excluded from the claim.